# Install MongoDB PECL for PHP 7.2.6 Issue

Tags: php, mongodb, curl, php-7, php-mongodb

I'm trying to install the php driver for mongodb.
I've got php 7.2.6 on Apache on Windows 10 64bit.
I've downloaded the right version of the dll for my system, putted it on php\ext dir, but when I try to run phpinfo(); I can't see the module loaded.
What's the problem?
Thank you so much for your help

P.S. I have another pc with the same environment and everyting works fine.
BTW, on the "issue" computer, I can't see the CURL module loaded too...strange!

Comment: Please give specific details. There are several existing answers with documented install steps in them. If you cannot show that you have basically followed the process then it's more than likely the question will simply be closed in duplicate of one of them. If in fact only to stop someone posting a copied answer from one of those. So detail in your questions here is important in order to resolve it.

Comment: Thank you. Just follow the basic steps and follow more than one questions here with no result. I put the dll in the ext dir, added the extension=mongodb in the php.ini, but on this computer it doesn't work

Comment: have you checked `php.ini` ?

Comment: On this pc I've installed the PEAR package too, but nothing. In the other pc I had no problem, event with no PEAR package installed

Comment: This is my php.ini file https://codeshare.io/5QdrVR
As you can see I have the curl extension uncommented too, but I can't see it on phpinfo();

Comment: have you restarted apache after making changes to `php.ini`?

Comment: Yes, restarted apache evey time

Comment: Maybe it's a sort of dll dependecies? Some dll that i have to put on windows system directory?